# What is the last Mysql Version supported in REDHAT 6?

Tags: mysql, redhat

Maybe not such a good question ! But my Linux admin is to busy to answer my doubts. SO:

I have all my Mysql servers running on 5.1.69 version(the free one) that comes with RedHat O.S. My users are forced to upgrade their Mysql Versions because of the Drupal and moodle needs !! 
  So i need to know if RedHat goes beyond  5.1.69 version or not. If not i will install a new version with no support or buy Oralcle support (which is not an option i think for my users as they are so cheap kkkkkkkkk)
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version in the RHEL6 x86_64 repositories is 5.1.71, and 5.0.95 for RHEL5 x86_64.

You can check this (if you have a RHEL support login) here:

https://rhn.redhat.com/rhn/channels/software/Search.do

Comment: Ok Phil let me get this right!? So these are the mysql versions that RedHat will give me support for! anything above this ones is on my own or get support form other company ?

Comment: These are the RHEL provided versions.  If you have support with Redhat, then they will (at least, should) support you as long as you are using the versions from their repositories.

Comment: Yes that was the question! we have RH OS support, but i need to upgrade my Mysql to a higher version of the one they provide in their Repo!

Comment: In which case you are either going to have to purchase an enterprise licence for MySQL, get 3rd party support, or get by with community edition support (e.g. forums).

Comment: Yes that was! what i was thinking as well ! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of supported platforms: http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html.

The MySQL yum repo is detailed here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/ - That has binaries for MySQL 5.5, 5.6 and 5.7.

Comment: I am looking for the Last Free edition support!

Comment: @Up_One Red Hat Software Collections (RHSCL) 1.1 provides MySQL 5.5 and MariaDB 5.5: http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/06/04/red-hat-software-collections-rhscl-1-1-now-ga/